# PyQt support for WebEngine on raspberry Pi 3 raspbian-stretch

Tags: pi-3, python, raspbian-stretch, qt

I have installed PyQt5 for Python3. However while I can import various modules into Python I am finding that none of the WebEngine modules import (WebEngine, WebEngineWidgets, WebEngineCore). They dont appear to be there.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, uic

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1366, 768)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.widget = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(Form)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.widget)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os, sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "ui/browser.ui")
    window = uic.loadUi(ui_path)
    window.widget.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://192.168.2.128:5000/"))
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there no support for the WebEngine modules of PyQt on the Raspberry Pi and if so then any other alternatives to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "doesn't work", otherwise this kind of question just reeks of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479).

Comment: Clarified as "do not import". Please remove from hold.

Comment: May I ask: wouldn't it be useful for others and increase your chance for a helpful answer if you post in detail what you have tried (your code, your command line input etc.) and the original error messages?

Comment: Examples added as requested. Though this is not a case of needing code assistance. Its a question of pyqt capabilities versus what is known to be available in qt.